# Conditionally Include Template Lines if Referenced Files from Variable List Exist

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

I would like to conditionally include some configuration in my Nginx virtual host based on whether a directory that's defined in a variable list exists (actually it's also based on whether a variable exists for the variable list below too, but I'm trying to keep it simple here).

The variable looks like this:

```yaml
nginx:
  sites:
    - name: example.com
      aliases: www.example.com
      tls:
        key: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        certificate: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    - name: anotherexample.com
      aliases: www.anotherexample.com
      tls:
        key: /etc/letsencrypt/live/anotherexample.com/privkey.pem
        certificate: /etc/letsencrypt/live/anotherexample.com/fullchain.pem
```

Presume that the directory `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/` exists, and the directory `/etc/letsencrypt/live/anotherexample.com` doesn't.

The above is used in the following template (`with_items: nginx.sites`):

```yaml
- name: Nginx Site Templates
  template:
    src: nginx/nginx_site.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/nginx/sites-available/{{ item.name }}.conf
  with_items: "{{ nginx.sites }}"
  notify: reload nginx
  tags:
    - conf
```

with "nginx/nginx_site.conf.j2" being partially:

```
server {

...

  {% if [MY CONDITION THAT I NEED HELP WITH] %}
  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate_key {{ item.tls.key }};
  ssl_certificate {{ item.tls.certificate }};
  {% endif %}

...

}
```

I gather facts about whether the directories referenced in `nginx.sites[].tls` exist with the following registered fact:

```yaml
- name: Register Fact About Available TLS Certificates
  stat:
    path: "/etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ item.name }}"
  register: tls_site_certificates
  changed_when: false
  with_items: "{{ nginx.sites }}"
    - conf
    - facts
```

For each site, I want to include those lines in the `if` condition of the template only if the directory referenced exists. I think I'm *almost* there, but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring it out. So far I have:

```
{% if tls_site_certificates.results | select('item.name', 'equalto', item.name) | select('stat.exists') == true %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` is to filter a list.
The first use `select('item.name', 'equalto', item.name)` is almost correct: with `selectattr` you keep only the elements of the same name as the current item.

But then you want to access a field of the first element, not to filter again (and no need to compare a bool with `true`):

```
{% if (tls_site_certificates.results | selectattr('item.name', 'equalto', item.name) | first).stat.exists %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's actually something I tried (there are _so many_ things I tried, that I didn't bother listing them all, but maybe I should :/ ) with the resulting error: `"TemplateRuntimeError: no test named 'item.name'`

Comment: Could have been a good idea to show all the things you tested and all the errors you got. I fixed my answer to use the right filter `selectattr`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I had to change it a little so that the fact registration only happened `when: item.tls.key is defined`, so that I could then use `item.tls.key` as the path to search for when gathering facts. This meant I had to also add `if item.tls is defined` into the template, but that works out fine.